# how to better organize a web service interface

Tags: wcf, web-services

I have a web service that's ~200 methods strong, implemented using .Net + WCF in a standalone service.
we're modelling the backing code to use different handlers for different methods,
but eventually there's still that one monolithic interface...
I used (and loved) RESTful interfaces in the past, especially for the way they break up a single interface into separate domains.
can that be achieved using web services, without splitting the web service?
would love to hear thoughts on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Why couldn't you define multiple WCF contract interfaces, all to be implemented by the single web service class, which you don't want to split up. You would then expose each interface as a separate service, and they just all happen to be covered by the same class.

Comment: would the service still listen on the same port, to multiple services? for instance have http://myservice/api1 and http://myservice/api2?

Comment: PS - I don't want to have both apis covered by the same class, I want the opposite - to have two separate interfaces and classes as part of the same service... so I can open a single client connection and have access to multiple interfaces.

Comment: So you want a client to have access to multiple services from one client proxy?

Comment: yep, I don't want to open multiple TCP connections.